# how to get values out of NSData object

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I am making a request to my database and in response I am receiving a bunch of data that I am putting into a nsdata object using NSURLConnection methods like so.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

The data in the NSData object has a identifier value for each section of code its represented by a UInt16 variable 1-what ever..

I would like to know how I could identifiy those values then start decoding the data.

my plan is to create a class with a method in it that I pass the data into from the method above. The receiving method would then divide the packet up and most likely pass each section off to a respective method that could then decode it  and/or do checks on it etc etc.

Im just not sure how I can identify those leading values that are data representations of UInt16 variables.

I hope I have made some sense, if you are able to make some suggestions or example code that would be awesome!

Comment: You need to learn more about pointers in C... You can access a pointer to they byes with [recievedData bytes] and from there can access any sized element at any offset

Comment: or you can convert NSData into NSString.... by the way what is your response????

Comment: ah right.. I was considering converting it into a string but was not sure f the implications. my response is a mixture of unsigned 32 bit integers and Strings. each value is preceded with a value number then the length of the string (if its a string) then the string or unsigned in value.. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, so convert it into NSString and do what you want... what's the problem in it.?

Comment: no problem I guess I just didn't know if that was something that was frowned upon or something.. felt like it shouldn't be that simple.. or maybe that it could do something crazy with memory allocation. But since I have some definitive advice on this sounds like its good to go :P  Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structure of the data, you have to parse it manually. Use `-[NSData getBytes:range:]` in a loop to iterate through the data and extract the components. Remember to use the `NSSwap...ToHost()` family of macros to convert the encoded numbers to the native byte order.

Edit: look up documentation and headers for `NSSwapLittleIntToHost()` and `NSSwapBigIntToHost()`. These are two of the many functions which convert external binary number representation to the native CPU byte order, and vice versa.

Comment: awesome! this really sounds like the stuff I want to be doing..  I'm not to sure to sure what your last line means (Remember to use the NSSwap...ToHost() family of macros to convert the encoded numbers to the native byte order.) If you have any added words for this that would help, but for now I will start researching this. :) thanks very much.

Comment: @C.Johns I added a bit more info on byte order functions.